# How to truncate Tomcat Catalina.out log to 3 months back

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, web-applications

My company wants us to save logs from the past 3 months. Catalina.out is getting too large on the linux server (Red hat). How can I remove everything in the log except for the last 3 months in the ONE catalina.out file.

Comment: You should start by not logging everything to catalina.out. Once you log to some _other_ file, you can enable date-based rotation to that file and delete individual files whenever you want. No need to magically truncate any particular file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a requirement slightly similar to you case. This is how I tackled the requirement.

Add following Linux commands into **Cron Scheduler**

`grep` the required date stamp i.e. 2022-05-07 and write to new file

```
grep "2022-05-07" > 2022_05_07.log // write lines which matches the data stamp
wc -l 2022_05_07.log // outputs how many lines captured
```

Clear the log of `catalina.out` file without stopping `tomcat` with the command below.

```
sudo cat /dev/null > /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.37/logs/catalina.out
```

Make note it is **not recommended** to delete the `catalina.out` while `tomcat` is running.

It will keep on logging to `catalina.out` which is removed already (**reference of the file is hold by the tomcat**) hence the space will not be released. So you will need to `restart` the `tomcat` sever to release the space.